# VBA: If Worksheet name in Workbook equals Combo Box value selected from Userform then copy that Worksheet and paste it into another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a Userform that will copy a specific sheet from Workbook A and paste it into Workbook B (essentially archiving that data). The Userform presents the user with a combo-box dropdown to select the sheet name to be copied. I receive a subscript out of range error however when using the sheets.copy command. Here is my code with names modified for ease of reading:

```
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Dim WorkbookA as Workbook
    Dim WorkbookB as Workbook
    Dim ComboBoxValue as String


    Set WorkbookA as ActiveWorkbook
    Set WorkbookB as Workbook.Open("C:File Path Here")

    With ThisWorkbook
        For Each ws In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Name = UserForm1.ComboBox1.Text Then
                ComboBoxValue = ws.Name
                Worksheets(ComboBoxValue).Copy _ 
                After:=Workbooks("Workbook B.xlsm").Sheets(Sheets.Count) 
                ' Run-Time 9 Subscript Out of Range Error occurs on line above ^
                ActiveSheet.Name = UserForm1.ComboBoxSelection.Text
                WorkbookB.Save
                WorkbookB.Close
                WorkbookA.Activate
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If
        Next ws
    End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of your error is improper refenceing of the workbook.  There are a lot of other issues, too.

- Unnecassary reference to `ThisWorkbook`
- Unnecassary loop through all worksheets
- Unnecassary renaming of copied sheet
- Unnecassry / incorrect references to the `ActiveWorkbook` and `ActiveSheet`
- No Error Handling
- Improper indenting

Your code, refactored.  This is written as a button click event in the UserForm.  Update to suit your needs.

```
Option Explicit

Const ArchiveFilePath As String = "C:\Path\To\ArchiveBook.xlsx"

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim WorkbookA As Workbook
    Dim WorkbookB As Workbook
    Dim wsName As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set WorkbookA = ActiveWorkbook

    wsName = UserForm1.ComboBox1.Text
    If wsName = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

    On Error Resume Next 'Handle possibility that Open fails
    Set WorkbookB = Workbooks.Open(ArchiveFilePath)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If WorkbookB Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Failed to open " & ArchiveFilePath, vbOKOnly, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Check if specified ws already exists in WorkbookB
    Set ws = GetWorksheet(WorkbookB, wsName)
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        ' Sheet already exists.  What now?
        MsgBox "Sheet " & wsName & " already exists in " & WorkbookB.Name & ".  What now?", vbOKOnly, "Error"
        WorkbookB.Close
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set ws = GetWorksheet(WorkbookA, wsName)
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sheet " & wsName & " does not exist in " & WorkbookA.Name, vbOKOnly, "Error"
        WorkbookB.Close
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ws.Copy After:=WorkbookB.Sheets(WorkbookB.Sheets.Count)

    WorkbookB.Save
    WorkbookB.Close

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Function GetWorksheet(wb As Workbook, wsName As String) As Worksheet
    On Error GoTo EH
    Set GetWorksheet = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
EH:
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. I appreciate the in depth response, I learned a lot simply by reading your improvements. This is month 1 of VBA programming for me, I still have much to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Change `Sheets(Sheets.Count)` to `Sheets(Workbooks("Workbook B.xlsm").Sheets.Count)`

In this context, `Sheets(Sheets.Count)` is referring to your source workbook object, so you must specify to count the sheets in the other book.

Comment: Unqualified `Sheets` is implicitly referring to `ActiveWorkbook`. `Sheets(Workbooks(...))` isn't fixing that.

Comment: This was the root error that I was searching an answer for. Thank you for your time and help. However I had to give the best answer to Chris Neilsen as he addressed other underlying issues that I hadn't even considered.

Comment: Sure, it is - but when he is performing the copy method, it is copying the sheet from the activeworkbook. BookB doesn't become the activeworkbook until the completion of that method. This would resolve the subscript out of range error he described.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon thats what I initialy thought too, then realised he only quoted _part_ of the relavent line of code.  So suggestion actually is `After:=Workbooks("Workbook B.xlsm").Sheets(Workbooks("Workbook B.xlsm").Sheets.Count)`. Clumsy, but would work for that line

Comment: @ChrisMeurer _but when he is performing the copy method, it is copying the sheet from the activeworkbook._ Actually no, it's not.  It's using `ws.Copy` , no reliance on `Active` anything

Comment: Not sure everyone is so dead set on arguing this point, but it doesn't make you less wrong. ws is being set to the object returned by `activeworkbook.worksheets`: "With ThisWorkbook
        For Each ws In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Name = UserForm1.ComboBox1.Text Then" ...

Comment: @ChrisMeurer what you say is true of the OPs original code. It's _not_ true of my code (when you said _when **he** is performing the copy method_ I assumed you were refering to me...) - no need to continue this, lets clean up the comment thread

Comment: @chris neilsen Nope .. I probably should have @ user'd that. Nice answer from you, sounded like op really appreciated the effort. Cheers